# VBA function not working within macro but does work on its own

Tags: excel, vba, function

I made a function to verify if a date is within a column on another sheet, and to return TRUE if so. When I test out the function on its own, it is able to function as intended. However, when I included it in a subroutine that is meant to use it as part of an IF statement, it will always return FALSE, causing it to run when it shouldn't. What part of the code is not correct?

```
Function IsDateInColumn(myDate As Date, dateColumn As Range) As Boolean
    ' Check if myDate is in the specified dateColumn
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In dateColumn
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If CDate(cell.Value) = myDate Then
                IsDateInColumn = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    IsDateInColumn = False
End Function


Sub DebugIfHolidays()
'
' TestInsertDeleteRow Macro
'

'
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim holidaysWs As Worksheet
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim targetRow As Integer
    Dim newdate As Date
    
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AAPL")
    Set holidaysWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Holidays")
    
    ' Get the current date
    currentDate = Date
    
    'Set the date being tested (B1 + 1 day)
    newdate = ws.Cells(1, 2).Value + 1
    
    ' Check conditions for row 1
    If newdate < currentDate And _
       WorksheetFunction.Weekday(newdate, vbMonday) <= 5 And _
       IsDateInColumn(newdate, holidaysWs.Columns(1)) = False Then
    
        
        ' Replace cell B2 with newdate and check if FALSE
        ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = newdate
        ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = IsDateInColumn(newdate, holidaysWs.Columns(1))
        
        
    End If
    
    
    End Sub
```

So if the macro worked as intended, when there is a holiday (November 23rd for example), the function should return TRUE, but it will still return FALSE when I run the macro.
I thought the issue would be that the dates are not formatted the same but already checked for that, and if that were the case then the function would also return false when tested outside of the sub.

Comment: You really want to loop through a million rows in column A of the Holidays sheet to find a single date? Try using `range.find` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `holidaysWs.Columns(1)` to `holidaysWs.Columns(1).Cells`

Giving it the entire column the way you did appears to have the effect of making your foreach look at the columns in your range of columns rather than the cells in your range of cells.

Comment: This worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

aedom1's answer is correct. I'd personally re-write that code to pull the column data into an array first, while also reducing to only the usedrange in the sheet.

```
Function IsDateInColumn(ByVal myDate As Date, ByVal dateColumn As Range) As Boolean

  ' Check if myDate is in the specified dateColumn
  Dim Temp As Variant, Ws As Worksheet, x As Long
  Set Ws = dateColumn.Parent
  
  Temp = Intersect(Ws.UsedRange, dateColumn)
    
  If IsArray(Temp) Then
    For x = 1 To UBound(Temp, 1)
      If IsDate(Temp(x, 1)) Then
        If CDate(Temp(x, 1)) = myDate Then
          IsDateInColumn = True
          Exit Function
        End If
      End If
    Next x
  Else
    On Error Resume Next
    Temp = CDate(Temp)
    IsDateInColumn = myDate = Temp
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  IsDateInColumn = False
  
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Find Date in Column

- To check if the function was working correctly, you could have put the line `ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = IsDateInColumn(newdate, holidaysWs.Columns(1))` after the `End If`.

```vb
Function IsHoliday(ByVal CheckDate As Date, ByVal HolidayColumn As Range) As Boolean
    IsHoliday = IsNumeric(Application.Match(CLng(CheckDate), HolidayColumn, 0))
End Function
```

```vb
Sub DebugIfHolidays()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = wb.Sheets("AAPL")
    Dim hws As Worksheet: Set hws = wb.Sheets("Holidays")
    
    Dim NewDate As Date
    
    With aws.Range("B1")
        If Not IsDate(.Value) Then Exit Sub
        NewDate = .Value + 1
    End With
    
    If NewDate >= Date Then Exit Sub
    If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(NewDate, vbMonday) > 5 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim hrg As Range:
    Set hrg = hws.Range("A2", hws.Cells(hws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    If IsHoliday(NewDate, hrg) Then Exit Sub
    
    aws.Range("B2").Value = NewDate
    ' The following is useless.
    ' It will never show 'TRUE' because of the previous 'Exit Sub'.
    'aws.Range("C2").Value = IsHoliday(NewDate, hrg) ' ?
    
End Sub
```